# In Javascript, how do I convert a string so it can be used to call a property?

Tags: javascript, properties, string

So, I have an associative array and the keys in the array are properties of an object. I want to loop through the array and in each interation do something like this:

```
Object.key
```

This however does not work and results in returning undefined rather than the value of the property.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a for ... in loop:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    //key is a string containing the property name.

    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;  //Skip properties inherited from the prototype

    var value = obj[key];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use the bracket notation property accessor:

```
var value = object[key];
```

This operator can even evaluate expressions, e.g.:

```
var value = object[condition ? 'key1' : 'key2'];
```

More info:

- [Member operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

Don't forget that the methods of `Array` objects, expect to work with numeric indexes, you can add any property name, but it isn't [recommended](http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful), so instead intantiating an Array object (i.e. `var obj = [];` or `var obj = new Array();`  you can use a simple object instance (i.e. `var obj = {}` or `var obj = new Object();`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Assuming `key` is a string, try `myObject[key]`