# javascript: How to use the variable value inside a Statement?

Tags: javascript

How can I use the variable value inside a Statement?
It goes like this:

```
var skillsSelect = document.getElementById("selUnidade");           
var unidade = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].text;
if ( unidade == "" ) {
    alert("Escolha uma Unidade de Estoque!");
    return false;
}
else
{
    alert("Cheguei!");
    self.opener.document.frmIncluir.id_Unidade.value = unidade; 
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking in this question. Which variable?  What statement? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Maybe you mean inside if else block? Note that each line of code is a statement. Your code composed of statements

Comment: I guess it might be the bracket notation property accessor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664660/in-javascript-how-do-i-convert-a-string-so-it-can-be-used-to-call-a-property

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = "Foo Bar " + unidade + " blah blah";
alert(message);
```

Comment: `string` is probably not the best variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Your value assignment syntax is OK. The problem will be with your code that targets the input on the opener page.

```
self.opener.document.frmIncluir.id_Unidade.value = unidade;
```

On this line, `frmIncluir` needs to be the form **name** (not ID) and `id_Unidade` needs to be the input element **name** (not ID).

If `id_Unidade` is the ID you could change it to:

```
self.opener.document.getElementById("id_Unidade").value = unidade;
```